# json data to table with multiple headers

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a hard time grasping how to get this done,

I have a json file with a menu card for a restaurant, and would like to get this data into a table but since it's a menucard it has multiple headers (like 'starters', 'main course', 'whisky', ...). it only contains the name and price of every object.

It's not a problem to parse the json, it's more of a problem to shape it into a table.

this is my json:

```
{
    "Drinks": [
    {
        "Beers vessel": [
            {
                "Name": "Jupiler / 33cl / 50cl"
                "Price": "2.00 / 2.60 / 4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Bruges Zot blond"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "extra tap Crescent"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "extra tap"
                "Price": ""
            }
        ],
        "Beers Bottle": [
            {
                "Name": "Brugze Zot brown"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tall Hendrik Tripel"
                "Price": "4.30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tall Hendrik Quadruppel"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Westmalle Dubbel"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Westmalle Tripel"
                "Price": "4:10"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Duvel"
                "Price": "3.90"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Lindemans Kriek 25cl"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Duchesse de Bourgogne"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hommelbier"
                "Price": "2.90"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Rochefort 10"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Chimay Tripel white"
                "Price": "3.90"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Chimay blue"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Orval"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "St. Bernard Abbot"
                "Price": "4:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Kriek Boon 37,5cl"
                "Price": "7:20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Boon Geuze 37,5cl"
                "Price": "7:20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Jupiler NA"
                "Price": "2:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hoegaarden"
                "Price": "2:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Rodenbach"
                "Price": "2:30"
            }

        ],
        "Soft drinks": [
            {
                "Name": "Coca Cola / light / zero"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Ice Tea"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Perrier 20cl"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Vittel 25cl / 50cl"
                "Price": "2:20 / 4:40"
            },
            {
                "Name": "San Pellegrino 50cl"
                "Price": "4:40"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Fanta Orange"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Sprite"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Gini"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Schweppes Tonic"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Schweppes Agrum"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tönisteiner Orange"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Squash (tonic + grapefruit)"
                "Price": "4:40"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tennis (tonic + orange)"
                "Price": "4:40"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Fristi"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cecemel"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cold milk"
                "Price": "2.20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Red Bull"
                "Price": "3.50"
            }
        ],
        "Fruit": [
            {
                "Name": "Apple Juice"
                "Price": "2:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Orange Juice"
                "Price": "2:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Grapefruit"
                "Price": "2:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Multi Juice"
                "Price": "2:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Fresh orange juice"
                "Price": "7.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Fresh lemon juice"
                "Price": "7.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Lemon squash"
                "Price": "8:00"
            }
        ],
        "Cocktails": [
            {
                "Name": "Mojito"
                "Price": "8:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Caipirinha"
                "Price": "8:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tequila Sunrise"
                "Price": "7:20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cuba Libre"
                "Price": "7:20"
            }
        ],
        "Children Cocktails": [
            {
                "Name": "Dragon Blood"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Green Potion"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Smurfs Cocktail"
                "Price": "2.50"
            }
        ],
        "Appetizers": [
            {
                "Name": "Sangria fresh fruit"
                "Price": "8:40"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Campari fresh fruit"
                "Price": "8:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Sherru fino"
                "Price": "4:10"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Pineau des Charentes"
                "Price": "4:10"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Kir"
                "Price": "4:20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Ricard"
                "Price": "4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Martini white / red / rosado / fiero"
                "Price": "4:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Martini Royal (Cava)"
                "Price": "6:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Aperol Spritz"
                "Price": "6:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Picon vin blac"
                "Price": "7.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Glass of Cava"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Bottle of Cava"
                "Price": "25.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Piper Heidsieck Champagne 75cl"
                "Price": "70.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Champagne Pommery Brut 37,5cl"
                "Price": "35.00"
            }
        ],
        "Spirits":
        [
            {
                "Name": "Cognac"
                "Price": "7.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Grand Marnier"
                "Price": "6:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cointreau"
                "Price": "6:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Amaretto Disaronno"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Gin Mare"
                "Price": "10.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hendrick's Gin"
                "Price": "10.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Gin Bombay Sapphire"
                "Price": "6:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Gin Monkey 47"
                "Price": "10.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Vodka Russian Standard"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Vodka Red Bull"
                "Price": "7:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tequila Patron Silver"
                "Price": "8:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Bacardi Blanco"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Havana 7"
                "Price": "6:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Sambuca"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Baileys"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Limoncello"
                "Price": "4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Jägermeister"
                "Price": "4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Gin Harrier"
                "Price": "4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Korenwijn Harrier"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Supplement soda"
                "Price": "2.20"
            }
        ],

        "Whiskey": [
        {
            "Blended Whiskey": [
                {
                    "Name": "J & B"
                    "Price": "5:00"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Johnnie Walker"
                    "Price": "5:00"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Jameson"
                    "Price": "5:00"
                }
            ],
            "Malt Whisky": [
                 {
                    "Name": "The Macallan 12 years"
                    "Price": "9:00"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Lagavullin 16 years"
                    "Price": "9:00"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Talisker 10 years"
                    "Price": "9:00"
                }
            ],
            "American Whiskey": [
                {
                    "Name": "Jack Daniels"
                    "Price": "5:00"
                }
            ],

            "Name": "Supplement soda"
            "Price": "2:00"
        }
        ],
        "House Wine": [
            {
                "White": [
                    {
                        "Name", "glass"
                        "Price": "3.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "carafe 25cl / 50cl"
                        "Price": "7:30 / 14:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bottle 75cl"
                        "Price": "22:50"
                    }
                ],
                "Red": [
                    {
                        "Name", "glass"
                        "Price": "3.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "carafe 25cl / 50cl"
                        "Price": "7:30 / 14:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bottle 75cl"
                        "Price": "22:50"
                    }
                ],
                "Rose": [
                    {
                        "Name", "glass"
                        "Price": "3.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "carafe 25cl / 50cl"
                        "Price": "7:30 / 14:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bottle 75cl"
                        "Price": "22:50"
                    }
                ],
                "Chardonnay": [
                    {
                        "Name", "glass"
                        "Price": "4:50"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "carafe 25cl / 50cl"
                        "Price": "9:10 / 16.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bottle 75cl"
                        "Price": "23.90"
                    }
                ],
                "Semi-Sweet Wine": [
                    {
                        "Name", "glass"
                        "Price": "4:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "carafe 25cl / 50cl"
                        "Price": "8:10 / 16.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "bottle 75cl"
                        "Price": "22.90"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

        "Wine Suggestions": [
            {
                "White": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Sancerre (Sauvignon Blanc) Dom Brochard"
                        "Price": "27.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Santa Gloria Reserva (Chardonnay) Chile"
                        "Price": "19:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Candela 1884 (Viognier) Argentina"
                        "Price": "24.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Muscle (Chenin Blanc) South Africa",
                        "Price": "22:50"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Chateau des Gravieres (Semillon / Sauvignon)"
                        "Price": "20:50"
                    }
                ],
                "Red": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Cotes du Rhone Rasteau Labartalas 2011,"
                        "Price": "26.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Santa Gloria Reserva (Carmenere) Chile"
                        "Price": "24.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Candela 1884 (Malbec) Argentina"
                        "Price": "24.50"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Beaujolais Villages Pardon"
                        "Price": "21:50"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Hot Drinks": [
            {
                "Name": "Coffee"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Small Coffee"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Decaf"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cappuccino (whipped cream),"
                "Price": "3.60"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Lait Russe"
                "Price": "3:10"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Hot Chocolate (with Callebaut)"
                "Price": "3.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Warm milk"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Glühwein"
                "Price": "6:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Irish Coffee"
                "Price": "7:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "French Coffee (cognac)"
                "Price": "7:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Grand Marnier coffee"
                "Price": "7:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Amaretto coffee"
                "Price": "7:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tea sachet"
                "Price": "2.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Loose tea"
                "Price": "3:30"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Infusion mint / orchard"
                "Price": "3:30"
            }

        ]

    }
    ],
    "To Eat": [
    {
        "Starters": [
        {
            "Name": "Soup"
            "Price": "5:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Shrimp croquettes (4 pieces) with salad"
            "Price": "12:50"
        }
        ],
        "Main Dishes": [
        {
            "Name": "Steak (with fries and salad),"
            "Subtext": "Nature, béarnaise, mushroom or pepper sauce"
            "Price": "22.70"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Stew with Bruges Zot (fries and salad),"
            "Price": "19:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Steak tartare"
            "Price": "18.70"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Hamburger"
            "Price": "18.70"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Soles (3 pieces)"
            "Price": "23:50"
        }
        ],

        "Small Dishes": [
        {
            "Name": "Mixed plate with:"
            "Subtext":  "Salame di Felino, mozzarella balls, sundried tomatoes, cheese cubes, bread and butter."
            "Price": "16:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mixed plate (above) with fried snacks"
            "Price": "22:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Assorted fried snacks"
            "Price": "13.80"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Deep-fried squid rings"
            "Price": "6.80"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Bruschetta (6 pieces)"
            "Price": "9:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Garlicbread (6 pieces)"
            "Price": "6:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Serving cheese cubes"
            "Price": "7:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Serving Salami"
            "Price": "8:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Serving mixed"
            "Price": "8.70"
        }
        ],
        "Pasta dishes": [
        {
            "Name": "Vegetarian spaghetti"
            "Price": "12:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Spaghetti"
            "Price": "12:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Children Spaghetti"
            "Price": "7.80"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Penne Arabiata"
            "Price": "12:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Chili con carne"
            "Price": "12:50"
        }
        ],
        "Salads": [
        {
            "Name": "Goat Cheese Salad"
            "Price": "17:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Salad shrimp croquettes"
            "Price": "17:50"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Chicken Salad"
            "Price": "18:20"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Salad with chicken, fresh pineapple"
            "Price": "19:20"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Salmon Salad"
            "Price": "19:20"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cold pasta salad with chicken"
            "Price": "17.90"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cold pasta salad with salmon"
            "Price": "18.90"
        }
        ],
        "Desserts": [
        {
            "Name": "Sabayon with fresh fruit and ice cream"
            "Price": "12.00, 9:50 from 2 persons"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Tiramisu"
            "Price": "5:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "creme brulee"
            "Price": "6:00"
        }
        ],
        "Tea Room": [
        {
            "Subtext": "14:30 to 17:30"
        },
        {
            "Ice": [
            {
                "Name": "Children's ice cream"
                "Price": "3.80"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Dame blanche"
                "Price": "8.60"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Icecream with Strawberry"
                "Price": "10.60"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Icecream with fresh fruit"
                "Price": "10.60"
            },
            {
                "Name": "whipped cream"
                "Price": "1:00"
            }
            ],
            "Pancakes / Waffles": [
            {
                "Name": "Sugar"
                "Price": "4.00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "butter"
                "Price": "4:20"
            },
            {
                "Name": "cream"
                "Price": "5:00"
            },
            {
                "Name": "chocolate"
                "Price": "5:50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Mikado"
                "Price": "7.50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "fresh fruit"
                "Price": "10.60"
            },
            {
                "Name": "fresh fruit / ice cream / whipped cream"
                "Price": "12.60"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm open for suggestions in javascript and even in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Post to your question what your data looks like, and what you've tried.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As suggested, we need to see your actual code  (and what you've tried) in order to help you. It's really hard for us to figure out what's going wrong in your code, just from a vague verbal description of what you're trying to do. Show us what you've done - especially if it's not working, and what you expect it to do, and what you observe happening instead.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something simple like following :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('json.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
?>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid #DDD" width="50%">
    <?php foreach($data as $cat_name => $category): ?>
    <tr style="background:#DDD"><td colspan="2"><?php echo $cat_name ?></td></tr>
        <?php foreach($category as $sub_category): ?>
            <?php foreach($sub_category as $entry_name => $entry): ?>
                <tr style="background:#EEE"><td style="padding-left:25px" colspan="2"><?php echo $entry_name ?></td></tr>
                <?php foreach($entry as $e): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:35px"><?php echo isset($e['Name']) ? $e['Name'] : '' ?></td>
                        <td style="padding-left:35px"><?php echo isset($e['Price']) ? $e['Price'] : '' ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```